# How can I make multiple keeper feeds?

Tags: chainlink

Since we have more than one keeper model, we have keeper to feed these keepers. This keeper feeds himself at the same time. When determining the keeper balance, we set it as "x" multiple the min balance. We set this value as "a" for the feeder and "b" for our other keepers. The feed keeper cannot trigger for every multiple "a" and "b".

For example, let's say we have a total of 4 keepers. 3 of them are normal working keepers and 1 of them is the keeper who feeds the keepers. 3 keeper's balance, 2 multiple the keeper's min balance; We have determined the balance of the keeper performing the feeding as 3 multiple the min balance of the keeper. Keeper reads balances of both its own and keepers and feeds it if needed.

Do you have any suggestions as to the reason for this? Or is there any other way to do this?
Sometimes the transaction detail is like this:
https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x5f19826f6c806913899badae88c81d7b3a77bee8ef2810290e124828734b90c5

Comment: not sure what the question is here exactly? Are you asking what's the best way to ensure multiple upkeeps are funded? Or is there some kind of funding issue that's blocking you? Need more detail here

Comment: Harry Papacharissiou , Since we have more than one keeper model, we have keeper to feed these keepers. This keeper feeds himself at the same time. We have a wallet that we keep a link to to ensure this. We are not able to automatically receive a link from this wallet and feed the keeper who does not feed. How can I finance multiple keeper's automatically?

Comment: I think basically you'd just register 2 keepers. One keeper to do your "thing" (or however many keepers), and another keeper to keep funding your keepers. There is an `addFunds` method (or something similar)